# Adding labels and descriptions to attachments

Tags: attachment

I have this code which will allow a user to add an a label and a description when making an attachment.

Scenario :

The custom primary object is Product_Review__c.

The custom child object used to make the attachment is Product_Review_Attachment__c

A custom list button for the child object brings up a VisualForce page with a "Choose File" button, Description Type picklist, a Description long text field,and an "Attach File" button (`action="{!processUpload}"`).

I would like to give the user the ability to simply enter a Description and NOT include a file, essentially turning the whole process into a way to leave a note. But I can't figure out the best way to include this into the code. Right now it is still creating the Product_Review_Attachment__c record - but not allowing the process to complete without a file to save as well.

I think it's all just a matter of a properly placed IF statement to prevent it from going into the SaveAttachment method, but I can't figure out where to identify that the user has neither a Description AND a file. (If they have a Description then they should be able to save without the file).

Here is the controller :

```
public class UploadAttachmentControllerProdRev {

    public String selectedType {get;set;}
    public Boolean selectedAwesomeness {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    private Product_Review__c contact {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody {get;set;}

    public String contactproduct {get;set;}

    public UploadAttachmentControllerVendorProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.contact = (Product_Review__c)controller.getRecord();
        //contactproduct = contact.Product__c;
    }   

    // creates a new Product_Review_Attachment__c record
    private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
        Product_Review_Attachment__c obj = new Product_Review_Attachment__c();
        obj.Product_Review__c = contact.Id; 
        obj.Product__c = contact.Product__c;
        obj.Description__c = description;
        obj.Document_type__c = selectedType;
        //obj.awesome__c = selectedAwesomeness;
        // fill out cust obj fields
        return Database.insert(obj);
    }

    // create an actual Attachment record with the Product_Review_Attachment__c as parent
    private Database.SaveResult saveStandardAttachment(Id parentId) {
        Database.SaveResult result;

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.body = this.fileBody;
        attachment.name = this.fileName;
        attachment.parentId = parentId;
        // inser the attahcment
        result = Database.insert(attachment);
        // reset the file for the view state
        fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');
        return result;
    }

    /**
    * Upload process is:
    *  1. Insert new Product_Review_Attachment__c record
    *  2. Insert new Attachment with the new Product_Review_Attachment__c record as parent
    *  3. Update the Product_Review_Attachment__c record with the ID of the new Attachment
    **/
    public PageReference processUpload() {
        try {
            Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();

            if (customAttachmentResult == null || !customAttachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save attachment.'));
                return null;
            }

            Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());

            if (attachmentResult == null || !attachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save attachment.'));            
                return null;
            } else {
                // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
                Product_Review_Attachment__c customAttachment = [select id from Product_Review_Attachment__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];
                customAttachment.name = this.fileName;
                customAttachment.Attachment__c = attachmentResult.getId();
                update customAttachment;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.AddMessages(e);
            return null;
        }

        return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
    }

    public PageReference back() {
        return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
    }     
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to add a condition to check description has been entered by user or not. So you have to add IF statement at the start of the **processUpload** method of your code. If description is blank or null then you have to add a page error. Like that :

```
***if(description == null &|| description == '')
{
    ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save record without discription.'));
    return null;
}***
```

Thanks,
Pragati Jain

Comment: Please see the answer guidelines - [answer] - code should be formatted into a code block and please do not ask for upvotes in the answer.

Comment: @PragatiJain - thank you for your help. Right now the error I am getting in my debug logs is in reference to line 34 which is "attachment.body = this.fileBody;" and comes before the processUpload method. So, wouldn't I still get that error if I were to put your statement in there ?

Comment: @PragatiJain - I can see the description==null would work, but that still does not prevent the system from attempting to upload a record which has a description but no attachment. Somehow I need to figure out if there is an attachment before it attempts to create one with the saveStandardattachment method.

Comment: You can check filebody is null or not.